# I keep getting the java:122 error: '.class' expected. How do I resolve it?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Averages{ //name class as public

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //initialized string using 'new'

        String Course;
        int knowledgemark;
        int communicationmark;
        int thinkingmark;
        int applicationmark;
        int average;
        int finalexam;
        int average2;
        String answer;
        int maxK;
        int maxC;
        int maxA;
        int maxT;
        int knowledgeweight;
        int communicationweight;
        int thinkingweight;
        int applicationweight;
        String Assignment;
        String Test;
        int average3;
        int weight;
        int weightaverage;
        int average4= 0;

        System.out.println("What class are you calculating for?");
        Course = Scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What's your knowledge mark for this course?");
        knowledgemark = Scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What's your application mark for this course?");
        applicationmark = Scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What's your thinking mark for this course?");
        thinkingmark = Scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("What's your communication mark for this course?");
        communicationmark = Scan.nextLine();

        average = ((knowledgemark + communicationmark + applicationmark + thinkingmark)/4);
        average = Scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your average for" + Course + "is" + average);

        System.out.println("Do you want to calculate your exam with your final exam mark? (yes or no)");
        answer = Scan.next();

        if(answer.equals ("yes")){
        System.out.println("What is your final exam mark?");
            finalexam = scan.nextInt();
            average2 = (((average * 70) + finalexam * 30) /100);
                System.out.println("Your final average in this course is" + average2);
                }

        else{
        System.out.println("You average for" + Course + "is" + average);
            }

            System.out.println("You can also calculate your marks with tests/assignments");
            Test = Scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What test/assignment are you calculating for?");
            Test = Scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is the weighting for knowledge?");
            knowledgeweight = Scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your knowledge mark for the test/assignment?");
            maxK = Scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is the weighting for communication?");
            communicationweight = Scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your communication mark for the test/assignment?");
            maxC = Scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is the weighting for application?");
            applicationweight = Scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your application mark for the test/assignment?");
            maxA = Scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is the weighting for knowledge?");
            thinkingweight = Scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your thinking mark for the test/assignment?");
            maxT = Scan.nextLine();

            average3 = (maxK * knowledgeweight + maxC * communicationweight + maxT * thinkingweight + maxA * applicationweight);

            System.out.println("Your final average for this test/assignment is" + average3);

            System.out.println("What is the weight of the test/assignment (10, 30, 50)?");
            weightaverage = Scan.nextInt;

            weightaverage = (average3 * weightaverage);

            System.out.println("Your assignment/test weighted is" + weightaverage);

            int length;

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("How many classes do you have?");

            length = scan.nextInt();

            int[] firstArray = new int[length];

            for(int i=0; i<length; i++){

                System.out.println("What is your course mark for each class in order" + (1 + i) + "?");

                firstArray[i] = scan.nextInt[];

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code. The error is near the bottom of the page. Thanks ahead of time!

Please hep me fix this as I do not know what to do

It is my only error left to compile.

Thanks and greatly appreciated!

Edit: Formatted to show code in one snippet.

Comment: Wow, I get 22 compile errors in that code. *"error is near the bottom"* and *"only error left"*!! Yeah, right!!!

Comment: Really, use the code that they fixed and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `()` in your call to `nextInt()` at

```
weightaverage = Scan.nextInt;
```

change it to something like

```
weightaverage = Scan.nextInt();
```

**and**

```
firstArray[i] = scan.nextInt[];
```

should be

```
firstArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
```

**And**, you aren't *consistent* with your `Scanner` name.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

needs to be

```
Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

if you're going to call `Scan.nextInt()`. Also, you are calling `nextLine()` (which returns a `String`) and assigning the result to `int` variables.

Comment: Seems better but now it results in more errors that are the same thing. String cannot be converted to int. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code corrected with suggestions made by Elliott Frisch.

To reiterate:

- You declared `Scanner` with the variable name `sc`, but used `Scan.nextLine()` in the remainder of the code. The correction is `sc.nextLine()`.
- `sc.nextLine()` cannot be converted to String. It returns an integer so for example, `int knowledgemark = sc.nextInt();` is correct.
- Some code was using `sc.nextInt;` or `sc.nextInt[];` which should be corrected to `sc.nextInt();`.

  ```
  import java.util.*;

  public class Averages { //name class as public

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //initialized string using 'new'

          String Course;
          int knowledgemark;
          int communicationmark;
          int thinkingmark;
          int applicationmark;
          int average;
          int finalexam;
          int average2;
          String answer;
          int maxK;
          int maxC;
          int maxA;
          int maxT;
          int knowledgeweight;
          int communicationweight;
          int thinkingweight;
          int applicationweight;
          String Assignment;
          String Test;
          int average3;
          int weight;
          int weightaverage;
          int average4 = 0;

          System.out.println("What class are you calculating for?");
          Course = sc.nextLine();

          System.out.println("What's your knowledge mark for this course?");
          knowledgemark = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What's your application mark for this course?");
          applicationmark = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What's your thinking mark for this course?");
          thinkingmark = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What's your communication mark for this course?");
          communicationmark = sc.nextInt();

          average = ((knowledgemark + communicationmark + applicationmark + thinkingmark) / 4);
          average = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("Your average for" + Course + "is" + average);

          System.out.println("Do you want to calculate your exam with your final exam mark? (yes or no)");
          answer = sc.next();

          if (answer.equals("yes")) {
              System.out.println("What is your final exam mark?");
              finalexam = sc.nextInt();
              average2 = (((average * 70) + finalexam * 30) / 100);
              System.out.println("Your final average in this course is" + average2);
          } else {
              System.out.println("You average for" + Course + "is" + average);
          }

          System.out.println("You can also calculate your marks with tests/assignments");
          Test = sc.nextLine();

          System.out.println("What test/assignment are you calculating for?");
          Test = sc.nextLine();

          System.out.println("What is the weighting for knowledge?");
          knowledgeweight = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What is your knowledge mark for the test/assignment?");
          maxK = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What is the weighting for communication?");
          communicationweight = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What is your communication mark for the test/assignment?");
          maxC = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What is the weighting for application?");
          applicationweight = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What is your application mark for the test/assignment?");
          maxA = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What is the weighting for knowledge?");
          thinkingweight = sc.nextInt();

          System.out.println("What is your thinking mark for the test/assignment?");
          maxT = sc.nextInt();

          average3 = (maxK * knowledgeweight + maxC * communicationweight + maxT * thinkingweight + maxA * applicationweight);

          System.out.println("Your final average for this test/assignment is" + average3);

          System.out.println("What is the weight of the test/assignment (10, 30, 50)?");
          weightaverage = sc.nextInt();

          weightaverage = (average3 * weightaverage);

          System.out.println("Your assignment/test weighted is" + weightaverage);

          int length;

          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("How many classes do you have?");

          length = scan.nextInt();

          int[] firstArray = new int[length];

          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

              System.out.println("What is your course mark for each class in order" + (1 + i) + "?");

              firstArray[i] = scan.nextInt();

          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: If you like my answer, or the effort given by @elliottt-frisch, please mark it as the answer! Cheers.